# Uploading compressed file to HDFS over thrift using python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, thrift

From the thrift IDL for hdfs, I see the following and only definition to write (Version: Hadoop-0.20):

```
// write a string to the open handle for the file
bool write(1:ThriftHandle handle, string data) throws (1:ThriftIOException ouch),
```

The data is of type string which is not going to work when trying to write any compressed file. But anyway I went ahead and tried using the above API to write my `tar.gz` file:

```
    pathName = ttypes.Pathname(os.path.join("/tmp", "data.tar.gz"))
    fd = open("data.tar.gz", "rb")
    thirftHandle = self.__client.create(pathName)
    b = fd.read(1)
    while b:
        self.__client.write(thirftHandle, b)
        b = fd.read(1)

    self.__client.close(thirftHandle)
```

The script worked fine and the file got created in HDFS but when I tried retrieving it using the following command:

```
hadoop dfs -get /tmp/data.tar.gz .
```

it is corrupted as expected when trying to decompress.

Is there no way to write binary data into hdfs over thrift?